# How can I exclude a particular category from my Wordpress homepage?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 2 pages in the Wordpress site. All 2 pages are showing posts. I need to restrict few categories in First Page and other few categories from Second Page.

```
   <?php
    function excludeCat($query) {
      if ( $query->is_home ) {
        $query->set('cat', '-3,-5,-23');
      }
      return $query;
    }
    add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'excludeCat');
    ?>
```

This one will not work because, It will block the category from all the 2 pages.

Answer (score 0):

I remember doing something like this in a recent project, this was our solution:

```
<div class="blog-categories">
  <h3>Categories</h3>
    <ul>
        <?php
            $args = array(
                'show_option_all'    => '',
                'orderby'            => 'name',
                'order'              => 'ASC',
                'style'              => 'list',
                'show_count'         => 0,
                'hide_empty'         => 0,
                'use_desc_for_title' => false,
                'child_of'           => 0,
                'feed'               => '',
                'feed_type'          => '',
                'feed_image'         => '',
                'exclude'            => '1',
                'exclude_tree'       => '',
                'include'            => array( 7, 8, 9, 10, 15 ),
                'hierarchical'       => 1,
                'title_li'           => 0,
                'show_option_none'   => __( '' ),
                'number'             => null,
                'echo'               => 1,
                'depth'              => 0,
                'current_category'   => 0,
                'pad_counts'         => 0,
                'taxonomy'           => 'category',
                'walker'             => null,
                'show_option_all'    => 'All',
            );
            wp_list_categories( $args );
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note the including and excluding of specific category IDs.

You can over a category in 'Posts > Categories' WordPress menu and see link on bottom left of screen to find category ID.

[Docs on wp_list_categories() here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/)

Answer (score 0):

I apply something like this in a recent project, this was our solution:

```
<div class="blog-categories">
<h3>Categories</h3>
<ul>
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'show_option_all'    => '',
            'orderby'            => 'name',
            'order'              => 'ASC',
            'style'              => 'list',
            'show_count'         => 0,
            'hide_empty'         => 0,
                // 'hide_empty'         => 1,
            'use_desc_for_title' => false,
            'child_of'           => 0,
            'feed'               => '',
            'feed_type'          => '',
            'feed_image'         => '',
            'exclude'            => '1',
            'exclude_tree'       => '',
                /*
                    ** Note: Hover over a category in 'Posts > Categories' WordPress menu and see link on bottom left of screen to find category ID
                */
            'include'            => array( 7, 8, 9, 10, 15 ),

                // 'include'            => '',
            'hierarchical'       => 1,
            'title_li'           => 0,
            'show_option_none'   => __( '' ),
            'number'             => null,
            'echo'               => 1,
            'depth'              => 0,
            'current_category'   => 0,
            'pad_counts'         => 0,
            'taxonomy'           => 'category',
            'walker'             => null,
                'show_option_all'    => 'All',
        );
        wp_list_categories( $args );
    ?>
</ul>
```